# Is HTTPS secure enough for PHP data transfer?

Tags: php, security, https

I have an app and use HTTP POST to access database via PHP scripts. For example,

```
https://www.someserver.com/scripts/request.php
```

and the parameters are inside the message body.

On the server end, the PHP script (request.php) will access the database and then return some data by using return:

```
return data
```

Are both ways secure enough?

Comment: Secure enough against what? What sort of SSL cert do you have?

Comment: Secure enough that the data transferred both ways is not going to be seen by any other. SSL should be the regular one, what are the options?

Answer (score 1):

> Are both ways secure enough?

You are however secure from the [`Man-in-the-Middle Attacks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). But since you haven't posted any code related to how the parameters are going to be inserted to be in your table , we can't say this is *100% secure.*

A **HTTPs** does not mean that your site is completely secure. It's the ***data flow*** that is sent in a secure encrypted manner. A malicious user can still launch an SQL Injection attack or an XSS attack provided if your code does not handle those data properly (filtering , escaping).

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS provides a) encryption of the data in transit and b) identification of the party you're communicating with so you can be sure you're sending the data to whom you think you're sending it. As long as you are using a strong cipher suite which has no vulnerabilities, so traffic cannot be decrypted even if it was intercepted, the data should not be visible to potential men-in-the-middle. You configure your web server with the ciphers it supports. You can use http://ssllabs.com to test their strength. Secondly, as long as you have a trusted certificate and you confirm its validity in your client, you should be reasonably safe that you're communicating with the right endpoint.

Having said all that, if you have some other giant backdoor in your server and the server itself is already compromised without you knowing, all this is moot. Security comes from having an airtight system all the way. Having TLS/SSL is great for one small part of that system, it says nothing about other possible attack vectors. You need only inadvertently send your SSL certificate insecurely via email, somebody intercepts and steals the certificate and he may be able to impersonate your server, while you're still trusting the certificate.

Comment: when you say "cipher suite", do I need to extra thing to secure the data? or what does it mean?

Comment: Cipher suite means the encryption algorithm which is used to encrypt the data when it's sent over TLS/SSL. Both parties need to support the same algorithm so one end is able to encrypt data and the other end is able to decrypt it, both it using the same algorithm. The TLS/SSL protocol supports that both parties negotiate and agree on the best algorithm that both support. You should configure your server to offer only algorithms which are strong, for which there is no known vulnerability. That may be quite a detailed technical thing to do. The defaults are often not bad though.